# Unity3D: Simple animations ending with a bit of offset

Tags: unity, 3d, animation

I'm trying to make a simple game with some cubes rotating 90º when the user clicks on them.

I've setup an empty game object, a simple cube nested, an animator, and two animations: RotateClockWise, RotateCounterClockwise.

The idea is: User clicks, the nested cube rotates 90 degrees, then comunicates the new translate component to the wrapper and the wrapper updates its transform (I'm doing this so I can have only two animations). So far, so good.

The thing is that I've noticed that, even though the animation is "90º", once I've clicked enough times, a small offset begins to accumulate and ends up, yeah, rotating 90ºm but starting on 20º, so I got a not aligned cube.

The "dirty" trick I've thought is doing a manual round to the closest quarter on each turn, but that seems something I shouldn't be doing, given how advanced is supossed to be this system.

Any idea of what's going on?

EDIT: This is the math on teh "endAnimation()" function that updates the parent object with the rotation of the child:

```
        float newX = _rootGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + gameObject.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x;
        float newY = _rootGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + gameObject.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
        float newZ = _rootGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + gameObject.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z;
        _rootGameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ));
```

Comment: Sounds like accumulating rounding errors. Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: There's no math involved on the code, only setters, getters and triggers for the animations (Whose transforms go from 0º to 90º). Someone on Twitter told me to check transitions and such, just in case one animation launches before the previous finishes, and it seems this has alleviate the problem, but it still happens.

Comment: You don't have to write the math yourself for math to happen. All animations and transformations in a game engine boil down to math. So the simple choice of setting a variable following an animation is also math, and the particular order or stacking of operations can impact the result. That's why I've asked to see a sample of your code — it makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late answer, but time hasn't been a commoditty I'd have these last days. I've updated the original post with the "endAnimation()" function I was using.Basically, I was adding eulerangles.component.

Comment: Ah. Calculating new rotations by doing math on Euler angles is almost never what you want. Do you get the same issue with the one-liner `_rootGameObject.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation;` ?

Comment: The problem does not arises, but I need to add the child's rotation to the root object (So the first rotation moves 90º, the second another 90º, thus making it 180º and so on). I've tried transform.Rotate, but the problem persists.

Comment: The child's rotation is the parent's rotation plus the child's localRotation already. You don't need to do the composition yourself, Unity handles it under the hood.

Comment: Oh, crap, yeah, I used localTransform instead of transform. Still, the offset persists after some quick alternative clicks. I'm thinking the problem is still on the animation setup. At least I've cleared some unnecesary math...